# Is possible to using single route to access multiple pages by controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have multiple pages I need to access them by id in database,I found difficult to access them in blade template.I decided to create single controller where I will be able to access them,So it is possible to do that?

My controller:

```
 public function  index(Request $request,$id)
 {
         $categories  = Category::with('subcategories')
                      ->get();
         return View::make(['index','pages.quote','pages.video','pages.music','pages.radio','pages.inspiration','pages.gospel','pages.image'], [
         'categories'=>$categories
     ]);

 }
```

Route:

```
 Route::get('test','NewsletterController@test');
 Route::get('newsletter','NewsletterController@create');
 Route::post('newsletter','NewsletterController@store');
 Route::get('/', 'MainController@index')->name('index');
 Route::get('quote/{id}','HeaderController@index');
 Route::get('video/{id}','HeaderController@index');
 Route::get('radio/{id}','HeaderController@index');
 Route::get('inspiration/{id}','HeaderController@index');
 Route::get('gospel/{id}','HeaderController@index');
 Route::get('image/{id}','HeaderController@index');
```

Blade view:

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav leftside mr-auto">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
       <li class="nav-item active">
         @if($category->id == 2 )
         <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('index', ['id' => $category->id])}}">{{$category->name}} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
         @endif</li>
       </li>
    @endforeach
 </ul>
```

Comment: Why you want to do that instead of creating another function?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve with this but you can do this as:

```
 public function  index(Request $request,$id){
     $categories  = Category::with('subcategories')->get();
     if ($id == 3){ // example
       $page = 'pages.quote';
     }elseif($id == 4){ // example
       $page = 'pages.video';
     }else{
       $page = 'index';
     }
     return View::make($page, ['categories'=>$categories]);
 }
```